What is the difference between the notations $\beth_{\beth_{\beth_\ddots}}$ and $\beth_{\omega_{\omega_\ddots}}$ for the first beth fixed point?
Reading some papers on set theory I have found these two different notations used for the first beth fixed point.

$\beth_{\beth_{\beth_\ddots}}$
$\beth_{\omega_{\omega_\ddots}}$

I don't think the second one is correct because $\beth_\kappa$ is not necessarily equal to $\kappa$ in that case without assuming GCH. Can somebody confirm and tell me why these notations are used and for what specific reason.

Do you have an example of the second notation being used (or the first, for that matter)?

@spaceisdarkgreen https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2348995/is-rudy-ruckers-theta-%ce%b8-the-same-as-%ce%98-and-also-the-same-as-the-omega-fixed-po/2358904#2358904 This is about the way Rucker uses this notation and about the second form I was thinking about how you are supposed to use ordinals as  indices and not cardinals.

Yeah, there's no good "ordinal-y" notation for $\beth$ numbers, so I wouldn't worry about that. The second one I would read as $\beth_\kappa$ where $\kappa$ is the least $\aleph$-fixed point, which is not necessarily a $\beth$-fixed point.

@spaceisdarkgreen This $\beth_\kappa$ could be well below $\beth_{\beth_1}$ right?

An aleph fixed point can be proven to exist. With forcing, you can make $\beth_1$ larger than the first aleph fixed point.
